# 304 htpp code in web services and Jax-ws

Tags: spring-ws

We are using :
 * at the service side webservices with Spring Ws
 * at client side Jax-ws

It seems there is no documentation at all about using ETAG & the 304 http code in webservices.
Sending back a 304 code seems to be already implemented in Spring MVC.

Do you know if with those two technologies implement this stuff is possible or and easy ?
Right now i dont know if i can skip sending back the usual response in Spring WS with just a HTTP Code.

Im using endpoint with JaxB at the server side.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I am not sure, but SOAP services should abstract from transport as much as possible. If you need caching based on HTTP capabilities, maybe REST and GET requests will be a better choice (note SOAP uses POST)?

Comment: I'm not sure ETAGs make any sense in the context of SOAP services. We're not talking about REST-style resources, we're talking about RPC.

Comment: I knwo that but we have a stack of 70 webservices & cant just throw them that so easily.